# Embed jersey in java application

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

I am trying to embed jersey server in my java application so that I could control programmatically its starting/stopping etc. I have found [this](http://crunchify.com/how-to-start-embedded-http-jersey-server-during-java-application-startup/) tutorial but it is for jetty 1.18.1 (rather old). Using the latest jersey version (2.22.1) it seems that there have been many changes in classes, namespaces etc and  the example shown in the above tutorial is not working.

Could someone indicate a way of embedding **last** version of jersey in a custom application? I believe it is doable but I cannot seem to find a reference, documentation, example or whatever...

Comment: The jersey user manual has plenty of examples on how to get it running on embedded servers; it just doesn't seem to have one built-in anymore which makes sense as there are plenty of stable servers available. Just take your pick. https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#d0e3151

Comment: Thank you. You should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: It is not an answer, I'm only telling you that the manual does exist.

Comment: Hi I am using org.eclipse.jetty version: '9.1.3.v20140225' with org.glassfish.jersey.bundles version: '2.7' in my application. So Can you explain where are you getting problem?

Comment: Actually I have no problem now. Gimby gave me the solution. I was trying to embed the jersey server and I missed the documentation part that he correctly mentioned. Please mark his comment as useful.

Comment: Post your findings as an answer :-)

Comment: You are right. I just did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gimby suggested, the [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#d0e3151) provides the answer. Jersey can be embedded in a java application, using another http server (such as jetty). In my case, I built a very simple working example project with these three steps:

1. Added the respective maven dependencies in my pom.xml. **Please note that I only have a maven dependency to the jetty connector of the jersey project. I don't have a dependency on the jetty server itself.** Having both of them would cause errors.

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
       <version>2.22.1</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-http</artifactId>
       <version>2.22.1</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Built a simple REST resource class

   ```
   import javax.ws.rs.GET;
   import javax.ws.rs.Path;
   import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
   import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
   import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

   @Path("testingservice/")
   public class TestingRESTService {

       @GET
       @Path("{requestID}")
       @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
       public String get(@PathParam("requestID") String requestID) {
           return "\n This is request with ID "+requestID;
       }
   }
   ```
3. In the main function added the code to start the embedded REST server

   ```
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.net.URI;
   import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;
   import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
   import org.glassfish.jersey.jetty.JettyHttpContainerFactory;
   import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

   @SuppressWarnings("restriction")
   public class TestingApplicationStartingRESTServerProgrammatically {

       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
           URI baseUri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(9998).build();
           ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(CrunchifyAPI.class);
           Server server = JettyHttpContainerFactory.createServer(baseUri, config);
           server.start();
       }


   }
   ```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with Tomcat instead of Jetty? I'm searching but can't find the equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to embed it on a lower level API in case you choose to change the web engine to something like Netty or Vert.X  You have to go to [`org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet-core/2.19/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/WebComponent.java#WebComponent.service%28java.net.URI%2Cjava.net.URI%2Cjavax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%2Cjavax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29)

You need to construct it with a `WebConfig` and you would need to create your own implementation of the HttpServletRequest/Response/Context classes.

You can go lower by building your own `ApplicationHandler`, but at that stage it's pretty much Jersey internals.  On the WebComponent level you still have the servlet API so it is easier to build what you need.